# ./bin/neo4j install not working

Tags: linux, neo4j

I am trying to install neo4j Linux version. I have created $NEO4J_HOME in my bashrc and cd $NEO4J_HOME works fine. However, when I try to run ./bin/neo4j install, I get "Legacy install now lives in the 'neo4j-installer' script" and nothing else. Am I doing something wrong? Running ./bin/neo4j-installer install gives warning that this is outdated version etc. That one starts installation, but ./bin/neo4j install doesn't do anything. I am installing neo4j-community-2.1.5 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to run it without installing? `./bin/neo4j start`. It should be accessible on port 7474 by default.

Comment: what linux are you running?